# How do I replace NFS4 ACL A::EVERYONE@:rxtncy with deny everyone who is not in my specified groups?

Tags: linux, acl

I have been asked to write ACEs such that only the owner and specific groups can access a directory.

nfs4_getfacl shows `A::EVERYONE@:rxtncy` is in the ACL. I tried setting `D::EVERYONE@:RWX` but that just added another ACE while leaving the `A::EVERYONE@:rxtncy` in place.

That's all. Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man nfs4_acl`:

> NFSv4 servers may return an ACL slightly different than one you set. For example, a server that always allows reading the attributes of a file may silently turn on the read-attributes permission, and a server that does not  support separate write-data and append-data permissions, e.g., may choose to turn off both if you set only one.

In other words, the operating system, configuration and filesystem type of the NFS4 server might be important, in case they place additional restrictions on what kind of ACLs can be applied.

Also from the same man page:

> NFSv4 ACLs are "default-deny"; that is, if a permission is not explicitly  granted by an Allow ACE, it is denied. [...] Deny ACEs should be avoided whenever possible.